# onmouseover in Dash HTML Components

Tags: python, html, jupyter, plotly-dash

I'm currently working with plotly/Dash and I have a problem regarding the Dash HTML components library.

So the code looks roughly like this:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from jupyterlab_dash import Appviewer

#... some unimportant dash properties

icon_black = 'icon_black.png'
icon_yellow = 'icon_yellow.png'

app.layout = html.Div(id = 'main_body', children = [
    html.Img(id = 'icon', src = icon_black)
])
```

What I'm trying to do is to change `src` to `'icon_yellow-png'` when hovering on the image but so far I couldn't find a solution to this. I'm currently trying to do this on CSS but I just wanted to ask if there is a simpler solution which I can directly put into the Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in Python with callbacks, but i find the CSS solution to be more clean for this particular use case. If you assign a class to the `Img` element,

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.Img(className='icon')])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

the content of the css file would simply be,

```
.icon{
    content:url("/assets/icon_black.png");
}
.icon:hover{
    content:url("/assets/icon_yellow.png");
}
```

Note that the above code assumes that your icon files are located in a folder called `assets` next to your application. If you put the css file in this folder also, it will be loaded automatically.